# CAAnimations, and updating the layer tree

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

This apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW3

shows how you to use an explicit animation to animate some property, and then to immediately set that property on the layer so that when the explicit animation is done, the final value of the property is correct.

However, setting a property directly on a layer also causes an implicit animation.  I feel like I am seeing a bug in my program to this effect, where both the implicit and explicit animations are running.

Can somebody explain how this works? In the sample code, is the implicit animation ignored when you set up an explicit one?

--- update ---

So the problem I am seeing specifically is i have an animation to change the position of a layer. It looks basically identical to the apple sample code

```
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.fromValue = startValue;
anim.toValue = endValue;
anim.duration = 1.0;
[theLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"myAnimation"];

// Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value.
position.position = endValue; // As a CGPoint
```

The glitch I am observing is first I see the position change fast (which I'm guessing is the implicit animation), then it goes slow (which is my animation).

One thing I just noticed that is different in my code is that the ID I give my explicit animation is "myAnimation", not "position". But that begs another question, if you give both animations the same ID ("opacity" in the apple sample code), and the implicit animation is set up second, why doesn't that one win out?

Comment: What problem are you seeing? How (code please) are you adding the animation?

Comment: Updated my question with some more info, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the off change somebody else encounters this, my problem was that two animations were being added to my layer. They were both animating the position property, but they had different IDs so both were running.

I solved my problem by wrapping the implicit animation in a transaction that turned off actions.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
theLayer.position = endValue;
[CATransaction commit];
```